# If $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx>0$ for every $a, b $ such that $b>a>x_0>0$ then ...

Tags: calculus, analysis

Usually in continuum mechanics when investigating the second law of thermodynamics one encounters a situation as follows

> $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx>0$ for every $a, b$ such that $b>a>x_0>0$ where $x_0$ is some fixed positive real number and $f:\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ is a continuous function.

My question are that

- What can we say about $f(x)$?
- What can we say about the $f'(x)$ whenever $f(x)=0$?

Intuition says that we may simply conclude $f(x) \ge 0$ over $\Bbb{R}$. And for the second question it seems that $f'(x)=0$ or does not exist.

I want to make a rigorous analysis. For starting the argument I use the mean value theorem for integration. So there exist a $c$ such that $a<c<b$ and $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=f(c)(b-a)$ so we have

$$f(c)(b-a)>0$$

what will be my next step?

Comment: About the derivative, wouldn't the first deduction imply that the derivative is zero at the zeros of the function?

Comment: Yes, intuitively but don't how to write it down. :)

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Did you check the edit queue? He edited the question. And yes, it might not be differentiable at the zeros, which could be relatable with some kind of phase change, but I'm guessing he has to tell if it is or isn't assumed to be.

Comment: @O.VonSeckendorff I apologize for that rude comment. Rough day.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 No worries, internet stranger. In the end we came to a conclusion in 2 comments. Hope it gets better for you. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rather go with a proof by contradiction from the very beginning: if $f(x)<0$ for some $x$, by continuity there is an interval $(a,b)\ni x$ such that $f(y)<0$ for all $y\in (a,b)$. But then $$\int_a^b f(y)\,dy<0$$.

**After edit:** If $f$ is differentiable at $x$ and $f'(x)> 0$, then for $y(\ne x)$ in a small interval $(x-\varepsilon, x+\varepsilon)$ it holds $\frac12f'(x)\le\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}\le \frac32 f'(x)$. Especially, for $y<x$ it holds $$f(y)\le \frac 12(y-x)f'(x)+f(x)< f(x)$$

On the other hand, if $f'(x)<0$, you have the specular situation $\frac32f'(x)\le\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}\le \frac12 f'(x)$ and, for $y>x$, $$f(y)\le \frac 12(y-x)f'(x)+f(x)< f(x)$$

So, if a function is $\ge 0$ for all $x$ and is differentiable in some point $x_0$ where $f(x_0)=0$, then $f'(x_0)=0$.

Comment: Ah! I am too silly! :D

Comment: Give me a moment I have a more interesting part which I forgot to include! Please take a look at the question again

Comment: Sorry for annoying again, can you modify your answer with the little last change in the question. It is not a big deal. :)

Comment: Let $f$ be a twice differentiable function which is positive for $x>1$. What can you say about $f(-35)$?

Comment: Let us just talk about $x>1$! :) So what can we say about $f(35)$? :)

Comment: All my arguments are local. Therefore, they do not depend on the open interval you are considering.